# How can I use Chrome Dev Tools timeline to find out which react components are updating?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, redux, google-chrome-devtools

I have implemented `react-dates` in my React/Redux app to have a nice calendar, but I am getting serious performance problems, and I can't properly indagate.

I have used the example component of the repo so It is not linked with my components state or redux store.

Every time I hover on a day on the calendar, it is that it triggers this whole mess:

[image]

Being the picker totally isolated from my application, I think the only updates that it triggers should be on the components itself. But it lags tremendously, and watching the stack on the timeline, It seems to me that there are a LOT of more actors involved.

I am not a big expert of JS perf analysis so I need some help, How can I understand from this what components are being updated?

UPDATE: I used the react dev tools to highlight what components are updating, and it seems that only the calendar it is updating. I cannot understand why the exactly same component in their demo it has no problem and in the context of my app is lags so much

Comment: Have you heard of the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)? This should integrate with React a lot better and it [even highlights updates](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-devtools/master/images/devtools-side-pane.gif).

Comment: @Aurora0001 yes, I did not notice the presence of that options, will play around with them right now to see if I can get more hints.. will update the questions if I find out something useful. thanks